# What is the mathematical basis of this multiplication table trick?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I recently came across this trick to come up with the multiplication table of any number greater than 10. For example, let's take 13.

The trick says, write down the multiplication table of the components - 1 & 3 vertically, place the values of each row of the two columns one after another (as long as both values are <10) to get the answer (13 X 3 = `'3'` `'9'`=39). This part is easy. However, if the second value is >10, then add the tens' digit to the first value, and then place this sum next to the ones' digit of the second value. For eg. for 17 X 6, we have in the 6th row - '6' and '42'. So, the answer is `6+4` `2`=`102`.

More examples, say for 16 -

`1   6` => `1` `6` = 16

`2   12` => `2+1` `2` = `32`

`3   18` => `3+1` `8` = `48`
...

`7   42` => `7+4` `2` = `112`

Similarly lets say 23 x 7 -

`14   21` => `14+2` `1` = `161`

I don't understand this carrying over the ten's digit business. How does doing that ensure the correct multiplication? Forgive me if this is too elementary!

Comment: Other than that you mean $17 \times 6 = 102$ (rather than $13 \times 6$, which equals $78$): Do you understand why we carry during ordinary multiplication?  Because ten $1$'s equal one $10$, and you can trade one for the other?  (Just as you can trade ten one-dollar bills for a single ten-dollar bill.)  That's more or less what's going on here.

Comment: (I apologize for the US-centric currency example.)

Comment: This is the distributive property.  What you're describing is the multiplication algorithm you learn in elementary school.

Comment: Hmmm, How do they teach multiplication in the first grade if this a "trick"?  This is how I was taught multiplication *was*.  Now it's a legitimate question as to *why* this works, but..... this is how I learned.  7x43.  You multiply the 7 times the three and get 21.  you write down the 1 and you "carry" the 2.  7*4 is 28 and you add the 2 you carried and add it to get 30 and you write that down and you get 301.  7x43 = 301.  What other way *IS* there to do multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because

$7 \times 16 = 7 \times (1*10 + 6)= (7\times 1)*10 + (7*6)$

$7*10 + 42 =$

$7*10 + 40 + 2=$

$7*10 + 4*10 + 2=$

$(7+4)*10 + 2 = $

$(11)*10 + 2 =$

$110 + 2 =$

$112$

If instead of seperating the "$*10$ with "+" signs, we made the into separate "columns" where column is understand to be the "ones" column, and then the "tens" column, and suppose we only did it one step at a time instead of all at once then we'd do:

$7\times 1|6 = ?|?|?$ ($7\times 6 $ is $42$ but $42$ is too big so we carry the $4$)

$7 \times 1|6 = ?|?|(4:2)$

$7\times 1|6 = ?|? + 4|2$  ($7\times 1$ is $7$ and we add the $4$ that we carried)

$7\times 1|6 = ?|7 + 4|2$ ($7+4 = 11$ is too big so we carry the $1$)

$7\times 1|6 = ?|(1:1)|2$

$7\times 1|6 = ?+1|1|2$ (We don't have anything in the "hundreds" column to multiply so we just put down what we carried.)

$7\times 1|6 = 1|1|2$

... I can't really format what I would have written on paper but it would look like this...(the red bars are imaginary and wouldn't be written but imagined...)

$\space \space \space{\color{red}|} 1\space\space {\color{red}|} 6$

$\times \space {\color{red}|}\space\space \space {\color{red}|}7$

$--------$

$ {\color{red}|}\space \space \space{\color{red}|}4\space \space {\color{red}|}2$

${\color{red}|}\space\space \space{\color{red}|}7\space \space {\color{red}|} \space \space $

$--------$

${\color{red}|}\space\space1{\color{red}|}\space\space 1{\color{red}|}\space\space 2$

Which is *exactly* how I learned to do it in elementary school 45 years ago.

How do they teach it now, that this seems like a "trick".  I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation. I think the *trick* part is that this can be quickly done while one is required to say, recite tables. As your explanation suggests, it's the standard multiplication method, but since this is easy to mentally do, it's a tables trick

Answer (score 0):

That's how additon works. E.g., 
$$\hphantom + 14\rlap{\,\color{grey} 0}\hphantom 0\\+\underline{\hphantom021}\\\hphantom +161$$